# TCP is sending wrong ACK during telnet connection

Tags: tcp, telnet

Here i am testing a telnet connection to a management-ip of device.
There is no telnet server running on 23 port. In fact no applications is listening on 23.Ideally the telnet connection should be refused when ever i tried to connect.But some times the connections is timing out instead of refusing.

Ideal Case:

```
$ telnet 10.145.65.46  
Trying 10.145.65.46...  
telnet: connect to address 10.145.65.46: Connection refused
```

Timedout case:

```
$ telnet 10.145.65.46  
Trying 10.145.65.46...  
Connected to 10.145.65.46.  
Escape character is '^]'.  
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

please find tcpdump on device which has above ip address in both cases.

Here
seadev01.olympus.f5net.com as telnet client

AdithyaVe1.com.telnet as telnet server

Ideal case:

```
3:02:02.950535 IP seadev01.olympus.f5net.com.39270 > AdithyaVe1.com.telnet: Flags [S], seq 853690436, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2527350559 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0  
23:02:02.950609 IP AdithyaVe1.com.telnet > seadev01.olympus.f5net.com.39270: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 853690437, win 0, length 0
```

in above case the connection is straight away rejected by sending RST packet.

Timed-out case:

```
1 Packet - 23:02:12.284611 IP seadev01.olympus.f5net.com.39272 > AdithyaVe1.com.telnet: Flags [S], seq 2750626194, win 14600, options [mss 536], length 0  
2 Packet - 23:02:12.284657 IP AdithyaVe1.com.telnet > seadev01.olympus.f5net.com.39272: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 2750626195, win 0, length 0  
3 Packet - 23:02:13.284453 IP seadev01.olympus.f5net.com.39272 > AdithyaVe1.com.telnet: Flags [S], seq 2750626194, win 14600, options [mss 536], length 0  
4 Packet - 23:02:13.284515 IP AdithyaVe1.com.telnet > seadev01.olympus.f5net.com.39272: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0  
5 Packet - 23:02:14.284836 IP seadev01.olympus.f5net.com.39272 > AdithyaVe1.com.telnet: Flags [S], seq 2750626194, win 14600, options [mss 536], length 0  
6 Packet - 23:02:14.284887 IP AdithyaVe1.com.telnet > seadev01.olympus.f5net.com.39272: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0  
7 Packet - 23:02:15.284560 IP seadev01.olympus.f5net.com.39272 > AdithyaVe1.com.telnet: Flags [R.], seq 1, ack 2802410946, win 0, length 0
```

In this case also device is sending RST packet but the connection is not
 terminated.Suppose the RST(2nd)packet is dropped some where in the n/w.  so telnet client is again sending SYN(3rd) packet but how the ack number is 1 in 4th packet.  i am not understating why tcp is sending 6,7 packets to client.
How the connection is closed in 7th packet even though it has wrong ack seq number 2802410946 instead of 2750626195(SYN seq number(2750626194) +1)

Comment: TCP retries the SYN several times. The device isn't online, hence the timeout. Off topic.

Comment: if that is the case in second attempt why server is sending RST packet(4th packet) with ack seq no 1.